# I Tried Everything. No Video With IE-11

Tags: internet-explorer

I upgraded to IE-11 from IE-8 last week. I don't regularly use IE, but software I use to daytrade with is based on IE. The did a major upgrade and I had to update to IE-11 for their software to work. Everything works fine, except for their CNBC stream. Its an embedded Flash-Player. But its not just this. No videos play at all Youtube, videos on websites... none of them.

Let me start by saying I have tried everything. Flash is current and enabled. Windows is all up to date. The ActiveX filter is off. I have gone through and tried every possible combination of the ActiveX settings and every other setting in IE both under the "advanced" tab and the "programs/manage add ons" settings.

And... when I go to Adobe's test page.... the little animated screen that has a tree growing with clouds floating by works fine. So apparently Flash is working fine, at least on Adobes site. https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelpx.adobe.com%2Fflash-player.html

But on top of that I have done a "clean flash uninstall" where you run Adobe's on-line cleaner and then go in and manually delete files; followed up with a fresh install. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/928315

Firefox and Chrome..... no problems at all.

This is the error on YouTube: "An error occurred, please try again later"

This is the error on MSN's Homepage videos when I try to play them: We're sorry, an error has occurred when playing video (video format is not supported).

HP Pavillion

Windows 7 Home Premium. All up to date.

SP-1

64 Bit

I even went back through my Windows updates and rolled the IE-11 update back to IE-8.... just to check...everything works fine with IE-8. All videos play as advertised. (I put IE-11 back)

I turned off my firewall (Comodo) and Windows Defender.... that didn't help.

I created a new user account for the PC... that didn't help.

I am friggin lost for ideas.

I wish I understood what I was looking at when I click "inspect element" as I mouse over the inoperative video and all that code comes up because somehow I suspect my answer can be found there, but this is one notch above my skills. But I think I can honestly say I've tried all the obvious fixes. I spent the entire weekend surfing forums.

This is driving me crazy... I mean I can live without it.... but honestly, this is the first computer thing in 20 years I have not been able to figure out for myself.

Any ideas?

- Let me add, I tried to post this on Microsoft Community and their forums just kept refreshing as I hit post. Figures.

---

---

---

NEW:

Edit ... this is a screengrab of the "inspect element" of a video on MSN while it was trying to load. ["inspect element screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRkZA.png)

Comment: It is highly improbable you actually tried every possible solution. Thank you for listing what you've done though, that is very helpful to us trying to figure out your problem.

Comment: Thank you both for responding.

Yes I tried adding YouTube under Compatibility View this weekend. Just tried it again to make sure. No luck.

Ditto with "use software rendering instead of GPU". No luck there either.

This is driving me nuts. Here's link to MSN page screengrab when I hit "inspect element": I hope this isn't the wrong rabbit hole, but this is what I got just now when I hit "inspect element" on an MSN page with a video that (obviously) didn't work. Don't know if this will help. It does have an error shown  https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5WNU.png

Comment: Pardon my unfamiliarity with how posting on this forum is set up, its a little different from what I am used to.

When I go to this page: https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/account_balances_in_SSE.html

I click on the video and now I am offered a "script debugging window" which I answer yes and this pops up: This is another screengrab. https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5WNU.png Again, not sure if this is useful but I'm trying, let me know if I need to do something else. This is new territory for me but I am willing to learn

Comment: Interesting.... I have Cmodo firewall installed and one of the options it has is to open a browser in a "container". When I opened IE-11 in the container it worked fine. So I went through and cleared all of the blocked applications. Tried to open IE again outside container, didn't work. So then I did a complete uninstall of Comodo FW-10 ... restarted computer twice as per their complete uninstall tool, tried IE-11... still didn't work. I took another screenshot of "inspect element" when a video on MSN was attempting to load (spinning wheel) ... here it is (below)

Comment: @junhyeoksong   (I added this to make sure you received notification)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try simple things first.

Go to Tools (Alt + X) and in the drop-down menu, there is Compatibility View settings.

Add https://www.youtube.com/ and try again. Let me know if that worked!

Comment: Also try disabling hardware acceleration, In IE, go to Tools, click Internet Options. Click Advanced tab, and then under Accelerated graphics, select the Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering check box. click apply, and ok. Restart IE.

Comment: please see my above remarks.  I still haven't figured out the proper forum intricacies of posting.